# 6 leaf nodes in Racket

Tags: racket

So I have the code below which perfectly implements(define myleaf (interior-node 'a (leaf-node 5) (leaf-node 6))). thats defined already

How can I implement a 6 leaf node for more data?

```
    define-datatype bintree bintree?
  (leaf-node
    (datum number?)
  )
  (interior-node
   (key symbol?)
   (left bintree?)
   (right bintree?)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "6-leaf node" that you mean a 6-ary tree, in which every non-leaf node has 6 children.

```
(define-datatype bintree bintree?
     (leaf-node
       (datum number?)
     )
     (interior-node
      (key symbol?)
      (first  bintree?)
      (second bintree?)
      (third  bintree?)
      (fourth bintree?)
      (fifth  bintree?)
      (sixth  bintree?)
     )
   )
```

define-datatype basically works like this:

- first argument: name of new datatype
- second argument: the name of the function you will use to test if something is an instance of that type
- next: all the different kinds of this datatype that can exist, their members their types

So in this case you would just add new members for each of the 6 children you want.